# What is Range V3 for MakeStream::iterate()?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, range-v3, c++-experimental

[C++ Streams](http://jscheiny.github.io/Streams/index.html) has `iterate()` which takes an initial value, `n` and a function, `f()` then produces first `n` followed by `f(n)`, `f(f(n))`...

```
auto stream = MakeStream::iterate(1245, [](int x) {
    if(x % 2 == 0) {
        return x / 2;
    } else {
        return 3 * x + 1;
    }
});
```

What does [Range V3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) have for this?

Answer (score 2):

In range-v3 you would create such a range with `view::generate`:

```
auto stream = ranges::view::generate([x=1245]() mutable {
    auto old = x;
    if(x % 2 == 0)
        x /= 2;
    else
        x = 3 * x + 1;
    return old;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c4e6fc0aabe328d)**